# Java do while loop increment

Tags: java, while-loop, do-while

```
int i = 10; 
int j = 0; 
do { 
    j++; 
    System.out.println("loop:" + j); 
    while (i++ < 15) {                //line6 
         i = i + 20; 
         System.out.println(i); 
    } ; 
} while (i < 2); 
System.out.println("i_final:" + i);
```

Output:

```
loop:1 
31 
i_final:32
```

Why the `i_final` is `32` and not `31`? As we can see the `do_while` loop has executed only once, so line 8 should also have executed only once, hence incrementing the value of "i" by 1. When did `31` increment to `32`?

Comment: The *contents* of the while loop has executed once, but the condition has been checked twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you are doing a while loop as (i++ < 15)  , it checks the condition and stop the loop if i++ is < 15 , But here when you do a do while loop j++ the loop goes 2 times and when it comes to while (i++ < 15)  it increaments the value of i by 1 and stops... so in second loop the value of i increases by one but the function inside the while loop remains the same as it stops when i++ is > than 15

IF you do the following you will get 31

```
int i = 10; 
int j = 0; 
    do { 
    j++; 
    System.out.println("loop:" + j); 
    while (i < 15) {                //line6 
         i++
         i = i + 20; 
         System.out.println(i); 
    } ; 
} while (i < 2); 
System.out.println("i_final:" + i);
```

Comment: i think you mean to put do{}while(j<2) ... besides i < 2 ... at the end of the do while loop

Answer (score 3):

While loop will be executed twice before its break.

```
while (i++ < 15) {                //line6 
                i = i + 20; 
                System.out.println(i); 
            } ;
```

First it increment to 11 .

Check with 15. Returns true.

Now it increments to 31. (`i = i + 20`)

now again while loop .

it increments the value .

Answer (score 2):

First time when while loop condition is checked i=11, after that i is incremented by 20, so i=31. Then while condition is checked again, when found that 31 < 15 is false i is still incremented by 1. So i =32